# How do I debug a filter program in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, filter, stdin, cmd, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug a [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29) program written as a C# console application. The usage of the program would be something like (executed from `cmd.exe`):

```
C:\MyDir\>type inputfile.txt | myfilter.exe
```

I have tried the obvious: Attach to the `cmd.exe` process and set a break point in my `Main` function. Software runs, Symbols aren't loaded, Debugger doesn't break into, Developer unhappy.

In the project properties, under `Debug`, it is possible to set Command line arguments. I don't have no stinking command line arguments. I want to have a file piped in to `STDIN`. How hard can that be?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I'm just not thinking today...

You just need to add a `Debugger.Launch()` call to your `Main` method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        // rest of your program goes here
    }
```

And Windows will be nice and let you debug your program. I knew this - this is how to debug custom actions in setup projects...

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach to myfilter.exe, the fact that it is launched from the command line is not important.  However if you have the project open in visual studio you just start debugging and it will attach automatically. Yes you can pass in command line arguments, either start the exe with the relevant arguments and then atatch or do it straight from visual studio go to the console application project properties and there is a command line arguments box in the debug section.